# Open problems in Hamiltonian Dynamics and Symplectic Geometry

Tags: soft-question, hamiltonian-formalism, education

I'm starting an undergraduate research on Mathematical-Physics and the topic I chose is Hamiltonian mechanics (and its formalism, Symplectic Geometry). I'm looking for some interesting open problems so that I can pick one to study now and then maybe take it to a graduate level later on. I was interested in integral invariants, topology of manifolds and Hamilton-Jacobi theory when I studied Analytical Mechanics.

Problem statement:

> *I would like some direction on where to look for these open problems in Hamiltonian Mechanics, that is, articles, pages or even keywords that could be used as useful material.*

The books I'm currently using are:
- "Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics", V.I. Arnold
- "Global Formulations of Lagrangian and Hamiltonian Dynamics on Manifolds", Lee, Leok and McClamroch
- "Semi-Riemannian geometry with applications to relativity", Barrett O'Neill
- "Gravitation", (you all know the authors of this one)

Comment: Does my question make sense now? I've narrowed it. Hope it's clearer.